# What to return if condition is not satisifed?

Tags: c#

The method looks as following:

```
private static List<string> SetPointObjectDefectRow(string[] row, string owner)
{
    const int zone = 54;
    const string band = "U";

    if (Helpers.NormalizeLocalizedString(row[7]).Contains(@"a") ||
        Helpers.NormalizeLocalizedString(row[12]).Contains(@"b"))
    {
        var geoPosition = UtmConverter.StringUtmFormatToLocation(zone, band, Convert.ToDouble(row[15]), Convert.ToDouble(row[14]));
        var beginGeoPosition = geoPosition.LatString + ", " + geoPosition.LngString;
        var result = new List<string>
        {
            owner,
            row[4],
            beginGeoPosition
        };
        return result;
    }
}
```

It's obvious that not all paths return something and the issue is I can't return null.

How to rearrange the method?

Comment: `return new List<string>();` ?

Comment: There are many different ways on dealing with a situation of no-data. For example you could  throw an exception, return an empty list. However we don´t know your scenario which is why I´m voting to close as opinion-based.

Comment: The issue is that I should create the structure with columns and rows. The structure has 3 columns. In case of empty or null list, the application is crashing because there's no columns.

Comment: Your app will crash anyway I guess, either because an excpedted column doesn´t exist or because the method itself throws an exception. So either way you have to handle both possibitilties in client-code.

Comment: If on else I add new list with 3 empty strings for each column, the application won't crash, but the result is not correct because the only rows that satisfies the condition should be displayed.

Comment: if your method cannot give any meaninful result if the parameters are not correct, just throw an exception and let the caller handle it. More than this, don't even handle your exception: let the program crash, be aware you have a bug in your program and fix it (i.e. check the parameters before calling the method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can initialize your List?

```
private static List<string> SetPointObjectDefectRow(string[] row, string owner)
{
    const int zone = 54;
    const string band = "U";
    List<string> result = new List<string>()
        {
            owner,
            string.Empty,
            string.Empty
        };

    if (Helpers.NormalizeLocalizedString(row[7]).Contains(@"a") ||
        Helpers.NormalizeLocalizedString(row[12]).Contains(@"b"))
    {
        var geoPosition = UtmConverter.StringUtmFormatToLocation(zone, band, Convert.ToDouble(row[15]), Convert.ToDouble(row[14]));
        var beginGeoPosition = geoPosition.LatString + ", " + geoPosition.LngString;
        result = new List<string>
        {
            owner,
            row[4],
            beginGeoPosition
        };

    }

    return result;
}
```

I usually do this when I want to create an assembler method for example to tranform a `List<X>` to another `List<Y>`, so if my `List<X>` is null I try to return an empty List of Y. I prefer to do this instead of throwing exceptions and getting my Dashboard full of errors. But It depends on how your codes works.

Comment: The issue is that I should create the structure with columns and rows. The structure has 3 columns. In case of empty or null list, the application is crashing because there's no columns.

Comment: @tesicg: the method is `private` so it's the class's (caller) responsibility to provide the correct input. If the method had been `public`/`protected` the input would have been validated as you've suggested

Comment: Dmitry's suggestion helped me.